# Lenovo M8 Tab - how to auto hide 3 buttons navigation bar in Chrome fullscreen

Tags: tablet, lenovo, navigation-bar

I have selected 3 buttons navigation as System navigation in Settings on Lenovo M8 Tab with Android 10.
Now I need it to hide automatically when not in use so that it is not visible in fulscreen Chrome.
It was possible before on other tablets or lower versions.
Is that somehow possible now?

Answer (score 0):

Only updated the Chrome and the problem went away, the 3 buttons navigation now hides automatically in fullscreen.